# Create SQL+ create Trigger on table employes

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the a table EMP and I want to create a trigger to "add 100 units at the salary of an employee when it's hired a new subordinate.

```
  CREATE TABLE EMP (EMPNO NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    ENAME VARCHAR2(10),
    JOB VARCHAR2(9),
    MGR NUMBER(4),
    HIREDATE DATE,
    SAL NUMBER(7, 2),
    COMM NUMBER(7, 2),
    DEPTNO NUMBER(2));

    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7499, 'ALLEN', 'SALESMAN', 7698, TO_DATE('20-FEB-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1600, 300, 30);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7369, 'SMITH', 'CLERK',    7902, TO_DATE('17-DEC-1980', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 800, NULL, 20);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7521, 'WARD',  'SALESMAN', 7698, TO_DATE('22-FEB-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1250, 500, 30);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES(7566, 'JONES', 'MANAGER',  7839, TO_DATE('2-APR-1981',  'DD-MON-YYYY'), 2975, NULL, 20);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7654, 'MARTIN', 'SALESMAN', 7698,TO_DATE('28-SEP-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1250, 1400, 30);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7698, 'BLAKE', 'MANAGER', 7839,TO_DATE('1-MAY-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 2850, NULL, 30);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7782, 'CLARK', 'MANAGER', 7839,TO_DATE('9-JUN-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 2450, NULL, 10);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7788, 'SCOTT', 'ANALYST', 7566,TO_DATE('09-DEC-1982', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 3000, NULL, 20);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7839, 'KING', 'PRESIDENT', NULL,TO_DATE('17-NOV-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 5000, NULL, 10);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7844, 'TURNER', 'SALESMAN', 7698,TO_DATE('8-SEP-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1500, 0, 30);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7876, 'ADAMS', 'CLERK', 7788,TO_DATE('12-JAN-1983', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1100, NULL, 20);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7900, 'JAMES', 'CLERK', 7698,TO_DATE('3-DEC-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 950, NULL, 30);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7902, 'FORD', 'ANALYST', 7566,TO_DATE('3-DEC-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 3000, NULL, 20);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7934, 'MILLER', 'CLERK', 7782,TO_DATE('23-JAN-1982', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1300, NULL, 10);
```

My trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER salary_increase
  AFTER UPDATE OF sal ON emp
  FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  UPDATE emp SET sal = sal + 100.0
        WHERE sal='800';
END salary_increse;
/
```

RESULT: `Trigger created.` (My problem--> the salary is not increased)

Comment: "*Default table*"?  "*Next trigger*"?  Are you following a tutorial?  It might help if you linked to it, because it's terribly unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Is an exercise for university... The code is my table only! I just want to create the trigger to add 100 at the actual salary of an employee in the moment when its hired a new employee!

Comment: have you tried to search for "mysql trigger tutorial" in google?

Comment: are you sure you are talking about MySQL? CREATE and INSERT statements doesn't look like MySQL

Comment: Sory, is not mysql, its SQL+

Comment: I've assumed that SQL+ means SQL*Plus and therefore Oracle (the varchar2 as well), so I've changed that tags. It's great that you're providing a base table and data but you [haven't even attempted to create the trigger itself.](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) That makes this _look_ like you've copied and pasted your homework and expect someone to do it for you. Have you made an attempt? What errors did you get.

Comment: And what's with all the abbreviations?  SQL supports (and you should use) longer table names.  Also, in the real world I'd hesitate to use a trigger for this: things get tricky if you need to remove records (for example, 'accidental' double entry of new employees).  I'd personally rather use a query to determine what (if any) 'hire bonus' a manager should get; especially as a strict reading of what you're attempting sounds like mangers with high turnover (constantly needing new employees) would benefit the most...  The query would be far more flexible.

Comment: Where sal = '800' when sal is a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger is declared as `FOR EACH ROW`, which is correct; but this means you don't need to run an UPDATE to change the value of a column, you can change it directly, e.g.:

```
CREATE TRIGGER salary_increase
  AFTER UPDATE OF sal ON emp
  FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  IF :NEW.sal = 800.0 THEN
    :NEW.sal = :NEW.sal + 100.0;
  END IF;
END salary_increse;
/
```

This is just an example - it uses the logic implied by your own trigger, but it does not implement the logic described by your assignment (*"add 100 units at the salary of an employee when it's hired a new subordinate."*). I've left that as an exercise for you.